# Vector space proof

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $\mathbb F$ be a field and let $V$ be a vector spaces over $\mathbb F$. Show that for all $w\in V$, $(-1_{\mathbb F}) \cdot w=-w$, where $1_{\mathbb F}$ is the multiplicative identity of $\mathbb F$.

I don't know what approach to take to prove this. At first, I was thinking it's pretty obvious but then I remembered we're talking about $\mathbb F$ and not a known field like $\mathbb R$, so I can't make assumptions about additive inverses and such...or maybe I can?
I think I'm overthinking it.

Any hints?

Thanks.

Comment: A field is a group in both the additive and multiplicative senses.  So an additive inverse exists for every element in the field, and a multiplicative inverse exists for every non-zero element in the field.

Comment: @abiessu I was taking that approach but then thought it wouldn't work since the field isn't specified. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just from the definition: $(-1)\cdot w+w=(-1)\cdot w+1\cdot w=(-1+1)\cdot w=0\cdot w=0$, so $(-1)\cdot w$ is $-w$.

Comment: So it wouldn't matter that the field is not specified? That's what threw me off, I thought it would be more complicated.